# configuring Airflow to work with CeleryExecutor

Tags: airflow

I try to configure Airbnb AirFlow to use the CeleryExecutor like this:

I changed the `executer` in the airflow.cfg from `SequentialExecutor` to `CeleryExecutor`:

```
# The executor class that airflow should use. Choices include
# SequentialExecutor, LocalExecutor, CeleryExecutor
executor = CeleryExecutor
```

But I get the following error:

```
airflow.configuration.AirflowConfigException: error: cannot use sqlite with the CeleryExecutor
```

Note that the `sql_alchemy_conn` is configured like this:

```
sql_alchemy_conn = sqlite:////root/airflow/airflow.db
```

I looked at Airflow's GIT (https://github.com/airbnb/airflow/blob/master/airflow/configuration.py)

and found that the following code throws this exception:

```
def _validate(self):
        if (
                self.get("core", "executor") != 'SequentialExecutor' and
                "sqlite" in self.get('core', 'sql_alchemy_conn')):
            raise AirflowConfigException("error: cannot use sqlite with the {}".
                format(self.get('core', 'executor')))
```

It seems from this `validate` method that the `sql_alchemy_conn` cannot contain `sqlite`.

Do you have any idea how to configure the `CeleryExecutor` without sqllite? please note that I downloaded rabitMQ for working with the CeleryExecuter as required.

Answer (score 22):

It is said by AirFlow that the `CeleryExecutor` requires other backend than default database SQLite. You have to use `MySQL` or `PostgreSQL`, for example.

The `sql_alchemy_conn` in `airflow.cfg` must be changed to follow the SqlAlchemy connection string structure (see [SqlAlchemy document](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/engines.html))

For example,

```
sql_alchemy_conn = postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@127.0.0.1:5432/airflow
```

Comment: Can I know How to add mysql connection instead of postgresql

Comment: @abhijeetmote msql connection string for sqlalchemy can be something like `mysql://username:password@hostname:port/database_name`

Answer (score 6):

To configure Airflow for mysql
firstly install mysql [this might help](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/07/howto-install-mysql-on-linux) or just google it

- goto airflow installation director usually /home//airflow
- edit airflow.cfg
- locate

  sql_alchemy_conn = sqlite:////home/vipul/airflow/airflow.db

and add # in front of it so it looks like

```
#sql_alchemy_conn = sqlite:////home/vipul/airflow/airflow.db
```

if you have default sqlite

- add this line below

  sql_alchemy_conn = mysql://:@localhost:3306/
- save the file
- run command

  airflow initdb

and done !

Comment: This is the tutoriall I have followed https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/installing-mysql-server-on-ubuntu/. Also, you need to specify user,password and database in the connection mysql://:user:password@localhost:3306/database

Answer (score 1):

As other answers have stated you need to use a different database besides SQLite.  Additionally you need to install rabbitmq, configure it appropriately, and change each of your airflow.cfg's to have the correct rabbitmq information.  For an excellent tutorial on this see [A Guide On How To Build An Airflow Server/Cluster](https://stlong0521.github.io/20161023%20-%20Airflow.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you run it on a kubernetes cluster. Use the following config:

```
airflow:
  config:
    AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:airflow@airflow-postgresql:5432/airflow
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is your sqlite.
As document on [Sequential Executor](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/executor/sequential.html) said:

> The SequentialExecutor is the default executor when you first install
> airflow. It is the only executor that can be used with `sqlite` since
> `sqlite` doesn’t support multiple connections. This executor will only
> run one task instance at a time. For production use case, please use
> other executors.

In other word: if you are using `sqlite` as `sql_alchemy_conn`, then you only choice is Sequential Executor.