# How do I connect Airflow to SQLite locally?

Tags: mysql, sqlite, ubuntu, airflow

I'm trying to try out Airflow for the very first time and I'm trying to connect it to a local SQLite database. But I can't seem to get my head around on how to actually do it.

I've read up on [Airflow's document](https://airflow.apache.org/howto/initialize-database.html), Set my `executor` to `LocalExecutor` and set up my `sql_alchemy_conn` to `sqlite:////home/myName/Programs/sqlite3/DatabaseName.db` but it doesn't seem to work as it throws an

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 21, in <module>
    from airflow import configuration
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    from airflow import configuration as conf
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/configuration.py", line 520, in <module>
    conf.read(AIRFLOW_CONFIG)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/configuration.py", line 283, in read
    self._validate()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/configuration.py", line 169, in _validate
    self.get('core', 'executor')))
airflow.exceptions.AirflowConfigException: error: cannot use sqlite with the LocalExecutor
```

error when I tried to run `airflow initdb`. I tried to google around and tried vipul sharma's solution [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36822515/configuring-airflow-to-work-with-celeryexecutor) and set the value of my `sql_alchemy_conn` to `mysql://:@localhost:3306/` but it still doesn't work as it throws an

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (1045, "Access denied for user 'myName'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")
```

error. I know that the answer should be really simple but I really don't understand how to so I hope you can guide me through on what to do/read.

Comment: Silly question but if it's a SQLite DB then why did you try to connect with a MySQL connection setting?

Comment: @ADyson Mostly due to my inexperience as I really don't know how to point it to my SQLite database. So after googling my problem and trying out some solutions, that was the most relevant answer to my problem and the one that doesn't show a `cannot use sqlite with the LocalExecutor` error.

Comment: yes but MySQL is a complete different database system from SQLite, they are different products. A connection would be made in a very different way. For a start, SQLite is file-based, whereas MySQL runs as a service listening on a port. So a solution relating to MySQL is really not relevant at all.

Comment: @ADyson I see, thanks for sharing that Dyson. would you happen to know what I could do to connect it to SQLite then?

Comment: sorry I don't know anything about Airflow specifically - I just saw this under the `mysql` tagged list of questions but saw "SQLite" in the title and wondered what was going on, so I thought I'd at least point out that mistake. Hopefully someone else can take it forward beyond that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use SequentialExecutor

"This executor will only run one task instance at a time, can be used for debugging. It is also the only executor that can be used with sqlite since sqlite doesn’t support multiple connections." [*airflow documentation*](https://airflow.apache.org/code.html?highlight=executor#airflow.executors.sequential_executor.SequentialExecutor)

You just didn't need to change to LocalExecutor, change it back to SequentialExecutor, change `sql_alchemy_conn` to point to `sqlite:////home/myName/Programs/sqlite3/DatabaseName.db` and stop airflow services (webserver, scheduler).

Execute `airflow initdb` then start up the services again.

Hopefully that works.

Comment: This works like a charm, thanks so much Hasan. If its not too much, could you share me the flow on what you did to get this answer? I've had similar problems like this on other APIs. I tried to google my problem but there wasn't an answer, so was I expected to read through the entire API first?

Comment: I've been working with airflow for about a year now and I just remembered that there some differences between executors that I've read somewhere in the airflow docs.
You can go through the quick start tutorial at:
https://airflow.apache.org/start.html
I guess it's best that you scan the whole documentation so you get an idea what it contains, then you can look back at ideas in details whenever you need to.